# Change Isotope filter from Any to other category on loading website

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have a code

```
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.color-shape'
});

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

$('.filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');

    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');

    // combine filters
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );

    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );

    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
    var value = '';

    for ( var prop in obj ) {
        value += obj[ prop ];
    }

    return value;
}
```

from Isotope but can't get it changed to other categories on loading. Can anyone help? I don't need 'all' on loading, I need to load a category from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I could load a specific category:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
filter: '.red',
itemSelector: '.color-shape'
});
```